# Detecting when a python script is being run interactively in ipython

Tags: python, interactive, ipython

Is there a way for a python script to automatically detect whether it is being run interactively or not?  Alternatively, can one detect whether ipython is being used versus the regular c python executable?

Background: My python scripts generally have a call to exit() in them.  From time to time, I run the scripts interactively for debugging and profiling, usually in ipython.  When I'm running interactively, I want to suppress the calls to exit.

**Clarification**:

Suppose I have a script, myscript.py, that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...do useful stuff...
exit(exit_status)
```

Sometimes, I want to run the script within an IPython session that I have already started, saying something like:

```
In [nnn]: %run -p -D myscript.pstats myscript.py
```

At the end of the script, the exit() call will cause ipython to hang while it asks me if I really want to exit.  This is a minor annoyance while debugging (too minor for me to care), but it can mess up profiling results: the exit prompt gets included in the profile results (making the analysis harder if I start a profiling session before going off to lunch).

What I'd like is something that allows me modify my script so it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...do useful stuff...
if is_python_running_interactively():
    print "The exit_status was %d" % (exit_status,)
else:
    exit(exit_status)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I stumbled on the following and it seems to do the trick for me:

```
def in_ipython():
    try:
        return __IPYTHON__
    except NameError:
        return False
```

Comment: what about the standard interactive shell you got with `python`?

Answer (score 5):

I compared all the methods I found and made a table of results. The best one seems to be this:

```py
hasattr(sys, 'ps1')
```

[image]

If anyone has other scenarios that might differ, comment and I'll add it

Comment: My tests were on Windows 10 and "shell" refers to both cmd and Git Bash (same results)

Answer (score 4):

Docs say that `sys.ps1` doesn't exist in noninteractive mode. Additionally, one can use `sys.flags` (for python 2.6+) to detect if we have used `python -i <whatever>`.

This scripts detects if we run interactively, non-interactively, and in post-mortem mode (which may be attributed to interactive mode if python interpreter is called using `python -i` implicitly and user thinks he landed into "interactive" console):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

# IPython recognition is missing; test here if __IPYTHON__ exists, etc.

if hasattr(sys, 'ps1'):
    print("Running interactively.")
else:
    print("Not running interactively...")
    if sys.flags.interactive:
        print("... but I'm in interactive postmortem mode.")
```

IPython support can be added as described by Mr Fooz.

Answer (score 3):

When invoked interactively, python will run the script in $PYTHONSTARTUP, so you could simply have that environment variable invoke a script which sets a global