# Detect executable (python? ipython?) in .pythonrc.py

Tags: python, ipython, python-2.x

I realised that I have a fairly large `~/.pythonrc.py`, notably helping with pretty printing and tab-completion.

But I'm now using `ipython` a lot and some of the commands executed in `.pythonrc.py` are annoying me and slowing it down at launch.

Instead of deleting the file or commenting it out, the better would be that I **execute the script conditionally depending on whether I launch `python` or `ipython`.**

How can I do that?
How to detect the launching script from inside `.pythonrc.py`?

NB: `sys.argv` is not helping when used in `.pythonrc.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the response used in [Detecting when a python script is being run interactively in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212779/detecting-when-a-python-script-is-being-run-interactively-in-ipython), ie in you pythonrc file, detect if the variable __IPYTHON__ exists:

```
def in_ipython():
    try:
        __IPYTHON__
    except NameError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```