# how to preserve module path of a module executed as a script

Tags: python, class, module, path, introspection

I have a function called `get_full_class_name(instance)`, which returns the full module-qualified class name of `instance`.

Example my_utils.py:

```
def get_full_class_name(instance):
    return '.'.join([instance.__class__.__module__,
                     instance.__class__.__name__])
```

Unfortunately, this function fails when given a class that's defined in a currently running script.

Example my_module.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from my_utils import get_full_class_name

class MyClass(object):
    pass

def main():
    print get_full_class_name(MyClass())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the above script, instead of printing `my_module.MyClass`, it prints `__main__.MyClass`:

```
$ ./my_module.py
__main__.MyClass
```

I do get the desired behavior if I run the above `main()` from another script.

Example run_my_module.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from my_module import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running the above script gets:

```
$ ./run_my_module.py
my_module.MyClass
```

Is there a way I could write the `get_full_class_name()` function such that it always returns `my_module.MyClass` regardless of whether `my_module` is  being run as a script?

Answer (score 0):

I propose handling the case `__name__ == '__main__'` using the techniques discussed in [Find Path to File Being Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296501/python-find-path-to-file-being-run). This results in this new my_utils:

```
import sys
import os.path

def get_full_class_name(instance):
    if instance.__class__.__module__ == '__main__':
        return '.'.join([os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]),
            instance.__class__.__name__])
    else:
        return '.'.join([instance.__class__.__module__,
            instance.__class__.__name__])
```

This does not handle interactive sessions and other special cases (like reading from stdin). For this you may have to include techniques like discussed in [detect python running interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212779/detecting-when-a-python-script-is-being-run-interactively-in-ipython).

Answer (score 0):

Following mkiever's answer, I ended up changing `get_full_class_name()` to what you see below.

If `instance.__class__.__module__` is `__main__`, it doesn't use that as the module path. Instead, it uses the relative path from `sys.argv[0]` to the closest directory in `sys.path`.

One problem is that `sys.path` always includes the directory of `sys.argv[0]` itself, so this relative path ends up being just the filename part of `sys.argv[0]`. As a quick hack-around, the code below assumes that the `sys.argv[0]` directory is always the first element of `sys.path`, and disregards it. This seems unsafe, but safer options are too tedious for my personal code for now.

Any better solutions/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import sys
from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_not_equal

def get_full_class_name(instance):
    '''
    Returns the fully-qualified class name.

    Handles the case where a class is declared in the currently-running script
    (where instance.__class__.__module__ would be set to '__main__').
    '''

    def get_module_name(instance):

        def get_path_relative_to_python_path(path):
            path = os.path.abspath(path)
            python_paths = [os.path.abspath(p) for p in sys.path]
            assert_equal(python_paths[0],
                         os.path.split(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))[0])
            python_paths = python_paths[1:]

            min_relpath_length = len(path)
            result = None
            for python_path in python_paths:
                relpath = os.path.relpath(path, python_path)
                if len(relpath) < min_relpath_length:
                    min_relpath_length = len(relpath)
                    result = os.path.join(os.path.split(python_path)[-1],
                                          relpath)

            if result is None:
                raise ValueError("Path {} doesn't seem to be in the "
                                 "PYTHONPATH.".format(path))
            else:
                return result

        if instance.__class__.__module__ == '__main__':
            script_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
            relative_path = get_path_relative_to_python_path(script_path)
            relative_path = relative_path.split(os.sep)

            assert_not_equal(relative_path[0], '')
            assert_equal(os.path.splitext(relative_path[-1])[1], '.py')
            return '.'.join(relative_path[1:-1])
        else:
            return instance.__class__.__module__

    module_name = get_module_name(instance)
    return '.'.join([module_name, instance.__class__.__name__])
```