# Detect if notebook is run interactively or being exported in nbconvert

Tags: python, ipython, nbconvert

I want to run some extra checks in my code when my notebooks are being exported using `nbconvert`.

**Is there any way to detect when this is the case?**

I already tried the solutions from [Detecting when a python script is being run interactively in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212779/detecting-when-a-python-script-is-being-run-interactively-in-ipython), without success: everything indicates the notebook is being run interactively.